# Batch not running as admin

Tags: batch-file, cmd

a Batch file I wrote needs admin rights to properly run. I have read and tried just about every possible thing and can't get it to work. For now my Batch is just a simple admin check:

```
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo no admin >>%~dp0admin.log )
exit /b 0
```

If I run it with ->right mousclick->run as admin it has admin rights, but not if I run it with windows scheduling or any of the following methods:

- using elevate.exe
- `run as /admin@domain`
- multiple diffrent scripts I found online (mainly here) that multiple useres reported working

But nothing worked (no error but my admin check echoed no admin...). I think it may have to do something with my useraccount (it's a pretty locked down work pc) but I thought if it works with two mousclicks there has to be a way to do it in a batch....

Answer (score 0):

When creating your task. Make sure to check `Run with highest Privileges`

[image]